# I want to generate ticket url given only story id, by not iterating projects

Tags: pivotaltracker

When we do basic github integration, given `[#ticket_id]` in commit message, it adds to the ticket.

Now I am listing my commits in my own report, and I want to convert all those messages having `#ticket_id` to `<a href="link_to_story">#ticket_id</a>` and hence I want to know easiest way to do that, given only story id, I want to make out link to the story.

Is there any api which will allow me to search by ticket_id/story_id, and give me its project id or the link itself.

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api/rest/v5#Endpoints)?

Comment: yes, I did not find any reference there to get story without project id

Comment: Well there you go, then!